# How to send array of data dynamically using navigationExtras?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass the request body while on the click of a link. I have a hotel list array and it contains list of hotels and its details.  If I click hotel title it will redirect to the hotel details page. while clicking on hotel title id has to be sent as request body. So that I have used navigationExtras. It works well if I send id as static value.  But I want to get the id dynamically from the hotelList. How can I get it?

```
  <div *ngFor="let hotel of hotelList">
  <h5 (click)="getHotelDetails()" >{{hotel.hotel_name}}<span 
  class="ratingStyle">
  </div>


  hotelList: Array<any>
  OnInit(){
  this.hotelService.getHotelsearch().subscribe(
   (res) => {
        this.hotelList = res;
      }
   }

   this.hotelList=[
  {
 api: "tbohotel",
hotel_id: "1507754",
hotel_index: 2,
trace_id: "92a4ee72-0d2c-4baf-9de7-f41b472f486f",
token_id: "ca7abc9d-cd5b-4b96-a405-8153f0382100",
hotel_description: "Hotel Konark is conveniently located in the popular Pahar 
 Ganj area.",
"rating": 3,
"hotel_name": "Hotel Dwarkadhish Intercontinental",

}
];

  getHotelDetails(){
  let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
  state : {
  api : "tbohotel",
  trace_id: "92a4ee72-0d2c-4baf-9de7-f41b472f486f",
  token_id: 'ca7abc9d-cd5b-4b96-a405-8153f0382100',
  hotel_code: "1507754",
  result_index: "2"
   }
  };
 this.router.navigate(['hoteldetail'], navigationExtras);
 }
```

Comment: please show what you get in `hotelList`, how you render it on template and how you call the `getHotelDetails()`

Comment: I have updated the question. pls look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it as below, you have to update `template` and `getHotelDetails()` as below :

```
 <div *ngFor="let hotel of hotelList">
  <h5 (click)="getHotelDetails(hotel)" >{{hotel.hotel_name}}<span 
  class="ratingStyle">
  </div>
```

```
      getHotelDetails(hotel: any){
        let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
          state : {
            api : hotel.api,
            trace_id: hotel.trace_id,
            token_id: hotel.token_id,
            hotel_code: hotel.hotel_id,
            result_index: hotel.hotel_index
          }
        };
       this.router.navigate(['hoteldetail'], navigationExtras);
     }

Component 2

    hotelDetails={};
     reqObj = {};
    state: any;

    constructor(private hotelService: HotelService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router){
 api: string;
    trace_id: string;
    token_id: string;
    hotel_code: string;
    result_index: string;
}
 ngOnInit() {
   this.reqObj = {
      api: this.state.api,
      trace_id: this.state.trace_id,
      token_id: this.state.token_id,
      hotel_code: this.state.hotel_code,
      result_index: this.state.result_index
        };
 this.hotelService.getHotelDetail(this.reqObj).subscribe(
      (hotelDetail) => {
        this.hotelDetails = hotelDetail;
        console.log("hotel:", this.hotelDetails);
      }
}
```

Comment: yeah... it's working.. thank you.. But I am facing one more issue in passing this values.. I have updated my question.  in that all state values are showing null.

Comment: Hi @swetha, I think your updated question is not visible yet, can you please verify whether your edit is approved or not

Answer (score 1):

You could try to directly send it as an object. Try the following

Caller

```js
hotelList: Array<any>

OnInit(){
  this.hotelService.getHotelsearch().subscribe(
    (res) => {
      this.hotelList = res;
    }
  );
}

getHotelDetails(api, traceId, tokenId, hotelCode, resultIndex) {  // <-- send values as arguments here
  const extras = {
    api: api,
    trace_id: traceId,
    token_id: tokenId,
    hotel_code: hotelCode,
    result_index: resultIndex
  };

  this.router.navigate(['hoteldetail'], extras);
}
```

Callee (Details component)

```js
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  api: string;
  trace_id: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.api = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('api'));
    this.trace_id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('trace_id'));
    console.log(this.api);
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: can you see my updated question. Because I have to pass 5 values to

Comment: I've updated the answer, please see if it works for you.

Comment: I got result already from this way.  But can you see the values in extra are hardcoded values.  I need to send the values dynamically from hotelList[].

Comment: You could just send the values as arguments to `getHotelDetails()` function and define the `extras` object with those values. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Could you please show more code? How are you sending values to the `getHotelDetails()` function.

Comment: Please see my updated question.  I can get response if the values are static(given in the state values.). But I need to send it dynamically from hotelList.  How to get these values from hotelList?